# Indent UITableView header label not working

Tags: uitableview

I am attempting to create a header label and to indent it so that it appears above the table view and not flush to the left side of the screen. I've implemented the following code, which is altering the appearance of the header label, but not the position.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,tableView.frame.size.width,30)];
    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0, headerView.frame.size.width, 30)];

    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    headerLabel.text = @"Header Label";

    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];
    return headerLabel;
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Return headerView instead of headerLabel, One more thing, give the height for header section - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 35;
}. And you can see your header view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return ur headerView, not headerLabel. That will solve ur issue.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to change this lines of code:

```
 UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,tableView.frame.size.width,30)];
 UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,     headerView.frame.size.width, 30)];
```

with:

```
 UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,30)];
 UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0, 100, 30)];
```

then increments or decrements value 10 for padding left, and 0 for padding top...

hope help